# SHA-512 returns NULL even using 2 DLLs (ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll)

Tags: c++builder, indy, sha2

My Environment:

- C++ Builder XE4
- using VCL component
- Indy 10.6.0.4975

I was studying to use MD5, SHA-1, and SHA-2s.

Unit1.cpp

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include <IdHashSHA.hpp> // SHA-1, SHA-2
#include <IdHashMessageDigest.hpp> // for MD5
#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    Memo1->Lines->Clear();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    String msg;
    msg = L"Hello, world";
    String hash;

    // 1. MD5
    TIdHashMessageDigest5 *md5;
    md5 = new TIdHashMessageDigest5();
    //
    hash = md5->HashStringAsHex(msg, IndyTextEncoding(TEncoding::ASCII)).LowerCase();
    Memo1->Lines->Add(L"MD5: " + hash);
    delete md5;

    // 2. SHA-1
    TIdHashSHA1 *sha1;
    sha1 = new TIdHashSHA1();
    //
    hash = sha1->HashStringAsHex(msg, IndyTextEncoding(TEncoding::ASCII)).LowerCase();
    Memo1->Lines->Add(L"SHA-1:" + hash);
    delete sha1;

    // 3. SHA-2 (SHA-512)
    TIdHashSHA512 *sha512;
    sha512 = new TIdHashSHA512();
    //
    hash = sha512->HashStringAsHex(msg, IndyTextEncoding(TEncoding::ASCII)).LowerCase();
    Memo1->Lines->Add(L"SHA-512:" + hash);
    delete sha512;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The result is as follows.

[image]

Then, I found the following:

[TidHashSHA512.isavailable is false on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379509/tidhashsha512-isavailable-is-false-on-windows-10)

According to the suggestion, I add two files to where the .exe file exists:

- ssleay32.dll
- libeay32.dll

Still, the SHA-512 returns NULL.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10.6.0.4975 is a VERY old version of Indy 10. The current version is 10.6.2.5485. You need to upgrade.

In any case, Indy 10 has native implementations of MD5 and SHA-1, those do not rely on any external hashing library at all.  But SHA-512 does.  Yet, you are not telling Indy which hashing library to use, such as OpenSSL.  You are not instructing Indy to load the OpenSSL DLLs so it can initialize itself to use OpenSSL's SHA-512 functionality.  As such, `sha512->IsAvailable` returns false, and `sha512->HashStringAsHex()` returns a blank string <sup>1</sup>.

This is clearly stated in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47383798/65863) to [the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47379509/):

> Indy provides an implementation that uses hashing functions from OpenSSL. To use it, you can either:
>
> - add the `IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders` unit to your `uses` clause, and then call its `Load()` function at runtime.
> - add the `IdSSLOpenSSL` unit to your `uses` clause, and then call its `LoadOpenSSLLibrary()` function at runtime.

In this case, since you are using C++ instead of Pascal, you need to add the corresponding `#include` statement to your code instead, either `#include <IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.hpp>` or `#include <IdSSLOpenSSL.hpp>`, and then you can call the relevant `Load` function, such as in your Form's constructor.

<sup>1: BTW, you should be using `IndyTextEncoding_ASCII()` instead of `IndyTextEncoding(TEncoding::ASCII)`.</sup>

Comment: I have overlooked the procedure you wrote as the accepted answer. Just now, I could get SHA-512 following either of the two suggestions. I appreciate it.

Comment: According to the update of the Indy, I will investigate for XE4 or I will consider to use Tokyo.

Comment: Thank you also for the IndyTextEncoding() usage. After checking the reason, I will consider to use it.